# Is it possible to output an aggregate query to a Map<Id, List<Contact>>

Tags: apex, soql, aggregate, aggregateresult

Is it possible to output an aggregate query like this:

```
Map<Id, List<Contact>> accountContactsMap = [SELECT aggregate query ...];
```

Where the Map **key** is the `AccountId` and the Map **value** is a `List` of related `Contact`'s for that `Account`?

If so, how should the query be constructed?

If not, what is the best approach to achieve this using apex?

Comment: Aggregate queries do not return individual records, but instead things like MIN, MAX, SUM, AVG, and COUNT values. You'd still be using a normal query, as explained in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an try following but it will count as 2 SOQL

```
Map<Id,Account> m = new Map<Id,Account> ([select id, name, (select id, name from Contacts) from account where id = ' your ACCOUNT ID']);

Account a = m.get('your ACCOUNT ID');

List<contact> cl = a.Contacts;

System.debug('***********'+cl);
```

Comment: Why does it count as 2 SOQL?

Comment: It's only one SOQL against the limits, not two.